# What to do with new answers to old off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, close-reasons, low-quality-posts

Every once in a while in the Low Quality Post review queue I come across a new answer on the form

> You should use tool X!

to a really old question of the form

> What tool should I use to do Y?

There are a number of things I could do in a situation like this:

1. Close vote (or flag) the question (since it is off-topic after all).
2. Downvote the question.
3. Choose delete for the answer (even though it answers the question).
4. Downvote the answer.
5. Choose "Looks OK" for the answer.

Currently, I only do #1 and then press "Skip". What is the right course of action here?

Comment: Definitely #1.  I personally choose between #3 and #5 depending on how thorough the answer is.  If it's still just a link, then I vote to delete for the link reason (#3).  If it kinda explains what the tool is or how it works (and it still not spam), then I leave it alone (#5).

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thanks for your thoughts! I also feel like instincively feel like #3 when the answer is just the name of a tool, but then on the other hand given the way the question is asked an answer like that is sort of the only answer you can give. Should it be deleted even though it technically answers the question as it is stated?

Comment: It's a judgement call, but I personally would still delete the answers that are basically only links.  This is only in the context of the VLQ review, and I would definitely _not flag_ as NAA.  Ultimately, it shouldn't matter too much if the question is so bad and vague to be deleted.

Comment: I'd say #1 - #4 and everything in between. Never #5

Comment: @TinyGiant What specifically is wrong with the answer? It does answer the question. On one hand I want to agree with you, but on the other none of the different reasons to "Delete" fits.

Comment: The no comment reason fits.

Comment: Downvote the answer and close the question

Comment: There's always #6: Innocently ask about the question on Meta and let nature take its course ;)

Comment: @TinyGiant and others recommending downvoting the answer: why? If the answer is a non-answer (e.g. link-only), you'll presumably already be voting to delete it, and if it's a good answer except for the fact that it's answering an off-topic question, then you're needlessly punishing someone for trying to make a positive contribution.

Comment: @Kyle see my answer below for my rationale.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the question is off-topic, I vote to close (and optionally downvote) the question.

If the off-topic question is answered, I use the following metric to determine my actions for the answers:

- If the answer is **not an answer**, **downvote** and **flag as Not an Answer** or **recommend deletion** of the answer.
- If the answer is a **bad answer**, **downvote** the answer.
- If the answer is a **good answer**, **refrain from voting** on the answer.
  <sub>(I may sometimes upvote if I'm in a good mood and it is an exceptional answer)</sub>

Comment: I agree with this outlook. Downvoting good answers doesn't really help anyone. Over time it can lead to less answers. This topic has been discussed to death, and this answer basically provides the overall consensus I have seen to date.

Comment: If the answer is in the bullet #3 category, I sometimes comment that it's not recommended to answer clearly off-topic questions, because it encourages people to keep asking such questions.

Answer (score 12):

I vote to close the question. Bad questions lead to bad answers often enough that having a button to indicate that the question is faulty and should be closed would be a useful feature.

Comment: Check. I should do #1. But should I do something more?

Comment: @Anders At the 10k level you get the ability to vote for question deletion. That would be my followup. If you can't delete the question, then downvote it

Answer (score 2):

When I run into these I usually opt to both close the question and delete the answer. Close voting alone doesn't really notify the answerer that they answered a question that they probably shouldn't have.

Often these kind of answers are link-only, so even if the question was on-topic the answer would still be low quality. Teaching the answerer that answers like these aren't appropriate is a big part of why we have the review.

Comment: That's were [auto-comments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) like [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26462516#26462516) come in.